# Is Remix Hardhat documentation outdated?

Tags: remix, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, browsers, remixd

In Chrome on Mac (the problem does not happen on Firefox), I'm trying to fully integrate a Hardhat project in a Remix IDE project, in order to compile the project in the same way, with both Remix's "Compile" button and terminal command: `npx hardhat compile`

- ✅ I'm connecting well the **Hardhat project**'s root directory (with
  `hardhat.config.ts` file), on **localhost workspace** with **remixd plugin**.
- ✅ I'm also able to connect **Remix IDE to Hardhat's local network** (`npx   hardhat node`)
- ❌ I'm getting **troubles integrating both compilers** (Remix & Harhat).

According to [Remix documentation, on Hardhat integration](https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/hardhat.html#enable-hardhat-compilation),

> If a hardhat project is shared through remixd and localhost workspace
> is loaded in Remix IDE, **there will be an extra checkbox** shown in
> Solidity Compiler plugin with the label **`Enable Hardhat Compilation`**.

[image: Remix Hardhat compiler image]

The above checkbox **`Enable Hardhat Compilation`** does not appear in current Remix version (February 2024). Following the official documentation, and being able to complete the other 2 steps, I cannot make both compilers to work in the same way.

- **Compiling with Remix** a `.deps` folder is created in `contracts`
  folder.
- **Compiling with Hardhat** I obtain different compiling result, specially resolving dependencies.

Am I missing any step or requisite, or maybe Remix is more updated than latest available documentation?

Thanks in advance.